# AEM 6.4 Text new line

Tags: xml, newline, aem

I am trying to get text in new line in one of the components in AEM 6.4.
I tried  '\n', '\r' but didn't work.

```
<instructionone
     jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
     text="1) line 1 .
           2) this will be line 2
           3) line 3 "
     fieldLabel=""
     name="./instructionone"
     autoWidth="false"
     xtype="menutextitem">
 </instructionone>
```

Comment: Where is ‘text’ going to be rendered? Please post your component HTML and where exactly the text is used

Comment: Did you try `<br/>`?

Answer (score 0):

If this is html you should be using `<br/>` as antonyh suggested.

If this value is going to be used in Java I believe you have to use a double slash when saving to a jcr property.

Try using:

```
<instructionone
   jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
   text="1) line 1 .\\n2) this will be line 2\\n3) line 3"
   fieldLabel=""
   name="./instructionone"
   autoWidth="false"
   xtype="menutextitem">
</instructionone>
```